# Change from button to plain text

Tags: php, html

I've got a button. And this button when clicked, will produce popup. The problem is I don't want it to be a button, instead, I just want it to be a plain text. All the function will be the same.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: show the code, or the way how you tried to resolved it.

Comment: This is part of "HTML 101".

Comment: <span class="yith-wcpsc-product-size-chart-button" data-chart-id="2013">See Size Chart</span>

I'm not sure whether to change the PHP code for the plugin or the HTM/CSS of the plugin..

My knowledge about HTML, CSS and PHP is basic, so any help here would be appreciate.

You can see the box I mentioned here > https://saradesign.my/product/kurung-jasmine-mustard/

Answer (score 0):

The "See size chart" element is not a button, it is actually plain text with a button-like style. You need to change it's CSS rules

If you want it to be simple black text on white background, change this:

```
.yith-wcpsc-product-size-chart-button{
    background: #0f0f0f;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 5px 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px -2px #dddddd;
}
```

to

```
.yith-wcpsc-product-size-chart-button {
    color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

and remove this

```
.yith-wcpsc-product-size-chart-button:hover {
    background: #3f3f3f;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @orfaust ! However, I can't change that even put the !important behind the css..FYI, with the plugin, I can change the padding, colour and etc. So it comes with selector..I believe this is related to PHP (I think)..

I tried to look this .yith-wcpsc-product-size-chart-button in the plugin file, but cant find it..sorry for my noobness here though..

But I really appreciated your effort!